# Can't launch calendar, contact, app store, etc

Tags: applications, contacts, calendar

### Issue

Whenever I try to launch an app, it opens for a split second and then disappears.

### System

- MacBook Pro
- Retina, Mid 2012
- Processor  2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory  16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics  NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB
- Software  OS X 10.9 (13A603)

### Console

App store says

```
10/25/13 11:42:06.515 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[593]: (com.apple.appstore.26432[2414]) Exited with code: 1
```

Contacts says

```
10/25/13 11:42:44.151 AM Contacts[2421]: Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting
10/25/13 11:42:44.153 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[593]: (com.apple.AddressBook.31536[2421]) Exited with code: 1
```

Dictionary says

```
10/25/13 11:43:03.592 AM Dictionary[2426]: Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting
10/25/13 11:43:03.594 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[593]: (com.apple.Dictionary.2144[2426]) Exited with code: 1
```

1Password says

```
10/25/13 11:43:30.354 AM com.apple.SecurityServer[16]: Killing auth hosts
10/25/13 11:43:30.354 AM com.apple.SecurityServer[16]: Session 100030 destroyed
10/25/13 11:43:30.356 AM com.apple.SecurityServer[16]: Session 100032 created
10/25/13 11:43:30.422 AM 1Password[2433]: Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting
10/25/13 11:43:30.425 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[593]: (com.agilebits.onepassword-osx.24144[2433]) Exited with code: 1
```

Calendar says

```
10/25/13 11:44:10.895 AM Calendar[2441]: Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting
10/25/13 11:44:10.898 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[593]: (com.apple.iCal.28368[2441]) Exited with code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to go to Apple Store and reinstall Mavericks.
Couldn't install from computer as app store was broken.